# Delete the content of a int * in C

Tags: c, arrays

If i have an array like this one:

```
int * array = ...
```

and if i want to delete it's content, what is the fastest and most efficient way to do this in C ?

Comment: Are you allocating memory to the contents using malloc?

Comment: What you have is a pointer, not an array; if it's pointing to memory you allocated with `malloc`, then you delete it with `free`.

Comment: Yes that's right, the pointer itself is not using the memory, it's only pointing to a location in memory. The answer depends on how you filled the content at that memory location

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking, what is in the "..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "deleting the content" you mean zeroing out the array, using [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) should work:

```
size_t element_count = ... // This defines how many elements your array has
memset(array, 0, sizeof(int) * element_count);
```

Note that having a pointer to your array and no additional information would be insufficient: you need to provide the number of array elements as well, because it is not possible to derive this information from the pointer itself.

Answer (score 4):

If you dynamically allocate memory for an array in C with

```
int* array = malloc(some_size);
```

then you free that memory with

```
free(array);
```

Fast and efficient hasn't got much to do with that procedure - it's just how it's done - but you can pretty much count on that there's no way to do it faster...

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that.